# Change progress tag color with its ID

Tags: html, css

I have created multiple progress and meter tags with ID assigned to it. Now i want to have different color for this progress tag and meter tag.

Is there a way to change color of these tag using there id ..? I found ways but it chnages color of all the tag at once.

Thanks in advance,
Vishesh.

Comment: And your representative/demo html would be..?

Comment: Sorry i didnt get your question. when i try to appy css using id it does not chnage :-

Comment: Like this #New {
 border: 1px solid black;
 color: Blue;
 background-color: Yellow;
}

Comment: Yes. Now: what's your HTML?

Comment: <progress id="New" value="5" max="26" ></progress>

Comment: If you are able to change the color using the tags ID kindly post your solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can style progress with css:

```
#New{
  color: #0063a6;
  border: 1px solid #0063a6;
  background: #fff;
}
```

for the Value:

```
#New[value]::-webkit-progress-value{
     background: #0063a6;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bronni/w30xw1ut/2/

Comment: Thanks for answer but it dose not work. In your fiddle just try giving any other color it does not take i gave color as #E52736 it didnt change.

Comment: Just to mention i am testing in chrome

Comment: Try this one. But just for webkit-based Browser: http://jsfiddle.net/bronni/w30xw1ut/2/

Comment: Works Fine.. Thanks a lot..!!    What about other Browsers..??

Comment: You can read a full article about this under http://html5doctor.com/the-progress-element/ 
Also more about styling.